# How can I merge cell 28 and 29

Tags: html, html-table

When I use **collspan=2 **on the cell 28 the table doesn't have a good view and my expectation is merge cell 28 and 29 without breaking.

```html
    <table width="100%" border="2">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">1</td>
        <td colspan="2">3</td>
        <td colspan="2">5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">9</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td rowspan="3">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">19</td>
        <td rowspan="3">21</td>
        <td colspan="2">22</td>
        <td>24</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">28</td>
        <td rowspan="2">29</td>
        <td rowspan="2">30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>32</td>  
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: So what happens when you do it.  `<tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">28/29</td>
        <td rowspan="2">30</td>
      </tr>` I am not seeing any weird rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo.  you tried `collspan`, but it's `colspan`.

the full table row should look like this:

```
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">28 + 29</td>
    <td rowspan="2">30</td>
  </tr>
```

A word of advice from a very old coder:
learning this level of table trickery was important in 1999,
before CSS and flexbox and grid came along.

Now it's irrelevant.

Comment: unsure how this is an answer.... What is the typo?

Comment: @epascarello Guessing it's because the OP spelled it as `collspan` in the question?

Comment: So that would be a close for a typo it that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

[image: table]

Please check the image @epascarello @bjelli